# Invalid method Code length on very long template/view

Tags: java, grails, view

I have a very long templates for report. It contains more than 50 Grails domain at once. But when I tried to load up to 25 domain, it said "Invalid method Code length". I did search on google and it recommend me to split / chuck the templates.

So I made the following changes:

before it was one template _template.gsp

but  now : _template.gsp and _template2.gsp

but inside _template.gsp I put code such as

Now the problem It won't allow to load model/objects that loaded in controller into template2 ....

in my controller:

```
Class AbcController{

def index = {
def myParrent = MyParrent.get(1);

def mode = [:];
model.obj1 = Obj.findAllByParrent(myParrent);
model.obj2 = Obj2.findAllByParent(myParrent);

...

model.obj50 = Obj50.findAllByParrent(myParrent);
model.obj51 = Obj51.findAllByParent(myParrent);

def str = render(template:"template", model:model);

render(str);
}

}
```

any idea why model loaded in _template.gsp but not recognized in _template2.gsp

edit:

_template.gsp would like this one (not as simple as this one, because for each domain object I have to display one by one its fields)

```
<html><body>
<div>${obj1}</div>
<div>${obj2}</div>
<div>${obj3}</div>
....
<div>${obj24}</div>
<div>${obj25}</div>
......
<g:render template="template2"/>
.....
</body></html>
```

_template2.gsp:

```
    <div>${obj26}</div>
    <div>${obj27}</div>
    <div>${obj28}</div>
    ........
    <div>${obj50}</div>
```

So in a page I would like to display about 50 domain at once (the purpose is for filling the form, so don't blame me if I have to display all the data at once ... )

Thanks

Comment: You didn't show us your template code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the model(s) into the other template:

```
<g:render template="template2" model="[key:value]" />
```

Comment: but how to pass the model from main template to sub template ?

Comment: Did you look at my example?  You can also read the docs (http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+render).